# Script to Run through each Bugzilla Bug and Select 'Save Changes'

Tags: mysql, perl, bugzilla

I need to run through each BugZilla bug individually and select the Save Changes button due to a previous problem. As there are over 8000 bugs it would not be possible to do this manually. I think the Perl Module WWW::Bugzilla will let me complete this by connecting to the bugzilla API.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW:Bugzilla;

my $bz = WWW::Bugzilla->new(    server => 'http://be-qa-01/',
                                email => 'test.email@test.com',
                                password => 'pass' 
                                bug_number => 8333 );


# show me the chosen component
my $component = $bz->component;
```

I'm, not sure how to go about this and would be grateful of any help.

Comment: If you think you actually need to click the button, I suggest using WWW::Mechanize. Make a list of the bug numbers and just iterate over it, each time calling the bug detail page first and then pressing a button.